# Nested maps in C++ with vectors of different types as values

Tags: python, c++, dictionary, nested, hashmap

I am trying to convert the following Python code into C++:

```
outer_dict = {}

outer_dict[0] = {}
outer_dict[0]["ints"] = [0]
outer_dict[0]["floats"] = [0.0]

outer_dict[0]["ints"].append(1)
outer_dict[0]["floats"].append(1.2)

outer_dict[1] = {}
outer_dict[1]["ints"] = [0]
outer_dict[1]["floats"] = [0.5]
```

Essentially, the data structure is a nested dictionary in python where the values of the inner dictionary are lists of different data types. The overall data structure looks as follows:

```
outer_dict 
{
  0: 
  {
    "ints": [0, 1]        // list of ints
    "floats": [0.0, 1.2]  // list of floats
  }
  1:
  {
    "ints": [0]          // list of ints
    "floats": [0.5]      // list of floats
  }
}
```

How can such a code be converted to C++?

Comment: Even in Python I'd say that data structure should at least be a mapping of int->some dataclass instead of nested dictionaries. And in C++ that's coincidenatly the easiest way to implement it.

Comment: you might try something like `struct my_data_t { std::vector<int> ints; std::vector<float> floats; }`, and then build a map from that `std::map<std::size_t,my_data_t> my_map`

Comment: Also note NEVER try to directly convert what you do in Python to C++. Understand how BOTH languages work, understand WHAT you are doing (algorithm/datastructure) and then reimplement in C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Pepijn Kramer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16649550/pepijn-kramer) mentioned you can use a struct containing vectors of int and float -

```
struct IntsAndFloats
{
    std::vector<int> Ints;
    std::vector<float> Floats;
};
```

Then you can initialize it like this -

```
std::vector<IntsAndFloats> outer_dict = {
    // 0 :
    {
        {0, 1}, // Ints
        {0.0, 1.2} // Floats
    },
    // 1 :
    {
        {0}, // Ints
        {0.5} // Floats
    }
};
```

See full code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/obce18qGd)

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer I felt there is no need of std::map since std::vector can suffice here